# Getting 401 error in postman using NextJS in Gitpod

Tags: next.js, gitpod

Thanks for looking at my issue.

I am learning NextJS, and using Gitpod to test my exercise project.
The code I wrote is just a simple API route which works when you type API route in the browser (it returns DATA in JSON as expected).

However when trying to check the API using postman (and Thunder VScode extension), I get 401 error.

I have tested similar code in Codesandbox, and it works fine using postman.

Can you please advise what am I missing?

Thanks,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Error 401 means "Unauthorized status code". It means you forgot to pass security data(tokens/password/login etc) or you passed incorrect tokens. Share codesandbox code at least

Comment: I have added three pictures. First one is NextJS API (very basic) Second pic is response in  browser (no problem) third pic is 401 GET result in Chrome Postman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved :) Thanks to Gitpod
Port should have been set to Public

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code works with browser and postman,

```
export default function handler(req, res){
  res.status(200).json({name: 'John Doe'})
}
```

Possible solutions:

1. Change https to http in posman
2. Delete .next folder + re-run project
3. Look at your gitpod settings, maybe you have some restrictions based on your profile

Comment: I have done all of them, but nothing changed. still postman, and Thunder respond with 401

Comment: check your gitpod api settings

Comment: you may let me know where can I find Gitpod API settings? Under Gitpod setttings, I couldn't find any relevant option to set/change API settings. Thanks

Comment: Try to check setting one by one, 401 is triggered by gitpod, try to contact gitpod support with your question

Comment: There is not much setting on Gitpod related to API settings. However, I have just sent a message to Gitpod support team and raised the issue. Thanks for your comments.